# How to remove part of a string array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
var questions = [
"text",
"text",
"text",
"text"
]
```

I would like to remove this:

```
questions[0]
```

I have tried this but it does not do anything:

```
questions.splice(0, 1);
```

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: The indexes starts at 0, Try instead `questions.splice(0, 1)`.

Comment: `questions.splice(0, 1)` is supposed to work. Did you check the content of `questions` after the execution of `questions.splice(0, 1)` what does it print?

Answer (score 3):

> I have tried this but it does not do anything:

No, that's not true. `splice()` does two things here:

1. It removes the item from the specified position (Modifies the original array).
2. It returns the removed item.

```js
var questions = [
"text1",
"text2",
"text3",
"text4"
]

var removedItem = questions.splice(0, 1);
console.log(removedItem);
console.log(questions);
```

If you really want to remove first item, you can use [`Array.prototype.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) which will remove the first item from the array:

```js
var questions = [
"text1",
"text2",
"text3",
"text4"
]
questions.shift()
console.log(questions)
```

Answer (score 1):

Splice will return the removed elements(s) from the array. It modifies the array in-place. To see the change, you can print it out after the splice.

```js
var questions = [
  "text 1",
  "text 2",
  "text 3",
  "text 4"
];

var question1 = questions.splice(0, 1); // Returns the removed item.

console.log(JSON.stringify(questions, null, 2)); // Display the updated list.
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

#### Output

```
[
  "text 2",
  "text 3",
  "text 4"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete first element, you have two way :

Way 1:  Use `splice()`
`questions.splice(0, 1);`

`splice(position_to_start_deleting, how_many_data_to_delete)` takes two parameter.
`position_to_start_deleting` : The zero based index from where to start deleting. `how_many_data_to_delete` : From indicated index, how many consecutive data should be deleted

Way 2 :  Use `shift()`
`shift()` removes an element from the beginning of an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `slice`:

```js
var questions = [
  "text 1",
  "text 2",
  "text 3",
  "text 4"
];

console.log(questions.slice(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

straight from [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)
are you sure it isnt working?

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Kiwi"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;

function myFunction() {
    fruits.splice(0,1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is a better source though.

Comment: Always avoid if possible posts from www.w3schools.com. Many of them are missguided.

Comment: @lealceldeiro perhaps, but this one is not

Answer (score 0):

This code will find the matching string or number type, get its index then removes it from array.

```js
var array = ["John", "Mich", "Sam"]; // Array
var val = array.indexOf("Mich"); // Find the [#] of Mich and store to into val

if (val > -1) {
  array.splice(val, 1);
}

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```js
var questions = [
  "text",
  "text",
  "text",
  "text"
];

questions.splice(questions.indexOf('text'), 1);

console.log(questions)
```